# Slack API - Link to custom URI scheme

Tags: uri, slack, slack-api, custom-url

I have a (working) custom URI scheme that opens an app in my local machine. It looks somewhat like this:

`customscheme://?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx?platform=xx`

I am trying to send the user a message using the Slack API including a link that opens the custom URI. It seems to work with mailto: links but not with mine.. The syntax I am trying is the following:

`<customscheme://?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx?platform=xx|Open Uri>`

or

`[Open Uri](customscheme://?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx?platform=xx)`

without success.

The thing is, I am able to create the link from the UI using the Link (Ctrl+Shift+U) functionality, pasting the exact same link from above. The outcome is exactly what I want, the text with the custom URI as the link (and it opens it after a security check).

Is there some security concern that keeps me from getting this done?

Answer (score 0):

I found that inserting some word before `?` then will work well

`customscheme://foo?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx?platform=xx`